# AWS Cloudformation IAM - Not able to create iam user

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am creating an IAM user using cloud formation but getting below mentioned error:

"API: iam:CreateUser User: arn:aws:sts::11111111111:assumed-role/MyCloudFormationRole/AWSCloudFormation is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateUser on resource: arn:aws:iam::11111111111:user/username1 with an explicit deny"

I have created MyCloudFormationRole and have given it full iam access (iam:*) and i am running cloudformation command using this role.

create stack command:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name my-users --template-body file://C:/template.yml --parameters file://C:/parameters.json --role-arn arn:aws:iam::11111111111:role/MyCloudFormationRole --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

Is there anything missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are not allowed to do something it is either because you lack permissions or someone explicitly forbids it. In your case the "explicit deny" suggests the latter is the case. The policies can be in various locations:

- identity policy
- resource policy
- session policy
- permission boundary
- SCP

You would simply need to check which one denies the request.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html